# override the "id" attribute of Html.EditorFor - not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

Trying to override the "id"  attribute of Html.TextBoxFor (MVC 3) so that it should look like:

```
<input type="text" name="Password" id="@idPasswordTextBox" value="@Model.Password" />
```

where "idPasswordTextBox" is defined as:
`string idPasswordTextBox = "passwordText_"+@Model.Key;` in the same cshtml file.

This is working fine if I use as :

```
<input type="text" name="Password" id="@idPasswordTextBox" value="@Model.Password" />
```

but not working if I do it this way:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { id = "@idPasswordTextBox" })
```

Looks like the "id" attribute is getting messed up. What am I missing? Can anybody help? I am new bee in ASP.net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What, exactly, is the output you are getting?  I'm guessing that the id is being set to the exact phrase @idPasswordTextBox.

Comment: I am not able to what is the exact output as this is a dialog . But this what I am trying to do : (trying to disable/enable textboxes depending on a check box is check): $(document).ready(function() { $("#@idCheckBox").click(function () { if ($(this).attr('checked')) { $("#@idPasswordTextBox").removeAttr('disabled'); } else { $("#@idPasswordTextBox").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); } }); });

Comment: What does it matter that it's a dialog?  You should still be able to inspect the generated html...  Regardless, just remove the quotes around @idPasswordTextBox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, i should've looked more carefully.  You don't want quotes around @idPasswordTextBox in your TextBoxFor method.  That is run on the server, so when you put quotes around the name it is being treated as a literal string.  Remove the quotes, and remove the @ sign in front of id, and it will work.

Its important to always remember what is running on the server, and what is running on the client.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { id = @idPasswordTextBox })
```

Comment: I am not able to what is the exact output as this is a dialog . But this what I am trying to do : (trying to disable/enable textboxes depending on a check box is check):  $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#@idCheckBox").click(function () {
   if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    $("#@idPasswordTextBox").removeAttr('disabled');

    
   } else {
    $("#@idPasswordTextBox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

   }
  });

});

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @id = "@idPasswordTextBox" })

did not work either

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { id = @idPasswordTextBox })
 Rocks . Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work in MVC4 - @anything is not valid Razor markup and throws HttpCompileException.